# Client side routing on Sapper Export Site

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I am building a Svelte Sapper site for my blog and I am using Netlify to host it. I have setup `sapper export` as build configuration so that the site is generated at build time and served statically.

I have a use case to build a URL shortener in my site as abcd.com/go/short sourcing the data from  Airtable. But issue is since it is exported [statically](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Exporting), it generates pages like `/go/redirect1.html`,`/go/redirect2.html` during build time and any link added to Airtable at later stage would result in 404.

Is there a way I can make this page to run the URL redirection logic at client side so that it can accept URL parameters and fetch from Airtable when requested rather than at build time ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client side routing on Sapper Export Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315115/client-side-routing-on-sapper-export-site)

Comment: I am not sure why my question was posted twice. I am deleting the other one. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Did you delete the duplicate where the answer was?

Comment: Nope. It was never answered.

Comment: Also, Svelte has stopped support for Sapper Development to support the same features as https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/kit